# How to remove a folder which starts with a colon

Tags: linux

How should I remove a folder which starts with a colon (e.g. `:q` in linux)

Comment: Can someone care to say why this is being downvoted. Just fed up of these annoying rules.

Comment: Because it is a very common question, answered in many many tutorials.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I do understand that it would have been answered in many many tutorials, but help varies at different levels and this is quite basic. Also do understand not everyone has many years of experience and may not be in a position to get to an answer quickly, hence I asked for help in this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
  rm -rf "./:q"
```

it is a FAQ.

If you have a space in your directory, use `rm -rf "./ :q"` for example.

You could add `-v` flag to `rm` to make it show all removed things. You could also add the `-i` flag to be interactively asked at each step.

I strongly suggest reading the output of [man rm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm), i.e. the man page of `rm(1)`

And reading the [advanced bash scripting howto](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) will be helpful.

Comment: I tried it, doesn't seem to work

Comment: What did not work? What is the behavior and outputs? Are you sure `rm` is not an alias or a function (try with `/bin/rm` instead).

Comment: works now, it had a space before the colon which I wasn't able to see when I did a ls command